# What is the keycloak docker compose Yaml file format for external postgres db connection URL

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile, keycloak

I need to setup the Keycloak docker server with the External postgres Database connection URL.
Here's my current yaml file content which is working with POstgres docker container image as mentioned

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
  keycloak:
    image:jboss/keycloak:latest
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

I checked the official documentation for passing external DB connection URL.
But exactly didn't get what changes will be needed in YAML file
ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

I tried removing the Postgres and depends_on section from services and passed the Database connection details in Kecyloak environment section in yaml but it did not worked for me

Can anyone suggest the correct YAML file changes to use PostgresDB connection URL

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers can see each other by their service name, so here service name `postgres` is actually the connection url for `keycloak` container.

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local

services:
  postgres: # Service name 
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres # <<< This is the address, change it to your external db ip/domain
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Comment: Is It possible to do not use the postgres Image/container ,
and just pass the Postgres ConnectionURL

Comment: Of course it is possible, make sure database user exists for keycloak.

Comment: Can you share the yaml file format for that 
we want only keycloak container and  external postgres Database connected keycloak using only Connection URL

Comment: Just remove everything nested under postgres

Comment: Tried below 
version: '3'
services:
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: localhost
        DB_PORT: 5432
        DB_DATABASE: keycloakLocal
        DB_USER: postgres
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: Adm!n@123
        KEYCLOAK_USER: localkeycloak
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: local
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
removed all postgres related data just passed environment variables 
also passed IP address instead of localhost 
still not getting connected

Comment: we also tried keeping the postgres under Services  and removed 
image: postgres
      volumes:
just kept the postgres environment with its details but getting below error then 
Service postgres has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.

Comment: Db addr is not localhost…

Comment: Btw you have a small typo on line 20. You need to add a space character after `image:`, otherwise `docker-compose up` command will give you an error.